# check whether a date falls in between date range concat with TO operator

Tags: php

I have following format `2016-06-06` TO `2016-06-12`

I want to know that whether my date i.e `2016-06-11` lies in between or not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP if condition for checking date range:

```
$compareDate = "2016-06-06 TO 2016-06-12";
$dateArr = explode(" TO ",$compareDate);
$starting_date = $dateArr[0];
$final_date = $dateArr[1];
$date = "2016-06-11";
if($date >= $starting_date && $date <= $final_date) { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: actually i have no start date and end date i have to check 2016-06-11 in 2016-06-06 TO 2016-06-12 which is cobine with "TO" OPERTAOR

Answer (score 1):

```
if($date >= $fome_date && $date <= $to_date) 
{   
    echo "yes";
}
else
{
    echo "no";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/UdIgq

i hope it will be helpful

Comment: actually i have no start date and end date i have to check 2016-06-11 in 2016-06-06 TO 2016-06-12 which is coMbine with "TO" OPERTAOR.either i have to split this to get start date and end date any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Dates can be compared just as numbers can be
So using

```
date > starting_date && date < final_date
```

Will be just fine for an if clause. Also if you have I would recommend you do this in the database part as dbs have built in queries for such occasions.

Comment: actually i have no start date and end date i have to check 2016-06-11 in 2016-06-06 TO 2016-06-12 which is coMbine with "TO" OPERTAOR.either i have to split this to get start date and end date any idea??

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you are using however if you have TO between 2016-06-11 and 2016-06-06 you can use split('TO') and it will leave you with the two strings